# MySQL query is slower as it accesses data lower on table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, raspberry-pi

I have a MySQL DB running on a raspi4 2GB on a USB>SATA SSD with python connector interface. When I run the query

```
UPDATE sessions
SET used = 1, date_created = %s, places = %s, loc_query = %s,
    resp_loc = %s, resp_json = %s, ip_address = %s, full_q_string = %s
WHERE used IS NULL
LIMIT 1
```

It works fast (~.1 sec) but as it finding rows lower on the list it get much slower (into 2-3+ seconds, by row ~9000 its 4-5 seconds). I thought this was from the db filling up but when I go back and free up rows 1-10 by NULLING all those filled in columns in the query and setting "used" = NULL, those first 10 rows are lightning fast even with the other 9000 rows populated, then when it starts writing to row 9001 it is slow again. I tried writing directiy to row a higher row

```
UPDATE sessions
     SET used = 1, date_created = %s, places = %s, loc_query = %s,
         resp_loc = %s, resp_json = %s, ip_address = %s, full_q_string = %s
    WHERE placeholder_id = 9002`
```

It works well/fast, but I need the logic/idea in the first query to work. Finally I tried restarting the Pi to try to flush RAM thinking it was some cacheing thing, but had similar expirence. Any input advice would be appricated :)

MySQL -(mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on aarch64 ((Ubuntu)))

Table columns:

```
                         placeholder_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                         session_key CHAR(5),
                         date_polled DATETIME,
                         date_created DATETIME(6),
                         full_q_string VARCHAR(2550),
                         ip_address VARCHAR(255),
                         places JSON,
                         loc_query LONGTEXT,
                         resp_loc LONGTEXT,
                         resp_json JSON
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL has a find a row where `user IS NULL`.  That can take longer and longer.

The solution is to create an index on `user`:

```
create index idx_sessions_user on sessions(user);
```

MySQL should be able to use the index to find a `NULL` row quite quickly speeding up your updates (with a little bit of overhead for maintaining the index on `insert`s and `update`s).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. using this made my whole program ludicrously fast. Thanks so much!!!!